# How do I add a private Github repository to package control in sublime text 3?

Tags: git, github, sublimetext3, package-control

I have created the files needed for a simple snippet library sublime package. I have these stored in a repository on Github. The git repo is private, due to the nature of the files; however, I need to be able to use them as a Sublime package so that other (pre-defined) users can install these snippets and they can be updated automatically, anytime there's a version change.

When I try to add a repository, I receive a 404 error. This tells me that there's lack of authentication on the request. I have then added oAuth to the url, and still no luck.

**Does anyone know how to use the 'Add a repository' Sublime Text 3 feature when your repository is private? And if this is at all possible?**

The alternative, which I have tried, is to manually clone the repo into the packages folder. This is not ideal as this negates the ability for the package to automatically update.